# TKinter Does Not Work

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tcl

I am working on Python v2.x windows os.
I notice tcl (including TKinter) IS installed while I am having Python installed.

But when I verify it by typing 'import tkinter' on Python IDLE, there is error:
*"ImportError: No module named tkinter"*

Could anyone give me some advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2,

```
import Tkinter
```

In Python3

```
import tkinter
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.x use `Tkinter` - see upper `T`.

In Python 3.x name was changed to `tkinter`

To work with both Pythons you can use

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off coding to support python 3 first, not as a fallback.